# How do I populate the Null Values based on Previous months value, when there are multiple continues Null values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, gaps-and-islands

Below is the input table:

| Month | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 |
| 2 | - |
| 3 | - |
| 4 | 300 |
| 5 | - |

**Expected Output :**

| Month | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 200 |
| 4 | 300 |
| 5 | 300 |

I did try using LAG function in SQL, as a result I was able to populate value for the immediate NULL values which is Month 2 in above case but next month which is Month 3 was still having Null values

Comment: look for gaps and island with your database name you are using

Comment: Solutions deeply vary from database to database. Specify the DBMS you're using first.

Comment: It is MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate the `LAST_VALUE` function to ignore nulls by creating partitions with:

- one non-null value
- following null values (excluding next non-null value)

then updating null values to the max for each partition.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(Value) OVER(ORDER BY Month) AS partitions
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT Month, MAX(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY partitions) AS Value 
    FROM cte
)
UPDATE tab
SET tab.Value = cte2.Value
FROM cte2
WHERE tab.Month = cte2.Month;
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Umrgu-8M).

Comment: That’s the canonical gaps and islands approach, and I suspect that it would perform better than the correlated subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a query using the `LEAD` function to convert your data into ranges as the following:

| from_month | to_month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 200 |
| 4 | 5 | 300 |

Then use the `update join` statement to update your table as the following:

```
Update table_name Set Value = D.Value
From table_name T Join
(
  Select Month As from_month, 
       Lead(Month, 1, (select max(month) from table_name) +1)
       Over(Order By Month) -1 As to_month,
       Value
  From table_name 
  Where Value Is Not Null
) D
On T.month Between D.from_month And D.to_month
Where T.Value Is Null;
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/I3IKkRSn)

Comment: That’s smart :) The downside is that it needs to join back on the original table, so possibly that’s less efficient than the updatable CTE solution.

Comment: Yea, I believe that @lemon answer would perform better, but I just wanted to post another way to do this :), thank you for your feedback,

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple correlation and an updatable table expression:

```
update u set value = v
from (
    select *, 
        (select top(1) value 
        from t t2 where t2.month < t.month 
            and t2.value is not null 
            order by month desc
        )v
    from t
    where t.value is null
)u;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the old hat solutions you can do it in one pass too:

```sql
with testdata as (
    select *
    from    (
        values (1, 200), (2, 50), (3,NULL), (4,300), (5, NULL), (6, NULL), (7, 10)
        ) x (mon, val)
    )
select mon, val AS orig
,   cast(substring(maxvalue2, 31, 30) as int) AS new
FROM (
        SELECT  MAX(CAST(mon AS BINARY(30)) + CAST(val AS BINARY(30))) OVER(ORDER BY mon) AS maxValue2
        ,   *
        FROM    testdata
    ) x
```